# JavaScript Async Call only works with alert()

Tags: javascript, firebase, alert

My code only works properly with inside

```
alert(tickerSymbol);
```

Im new to JavaScript so Im not sure why this is happening. Can Someone help me understand why the timeout of the alert fixes my problem?

```
database.ref("users")...
```

Without the alert my second firebase call above is never implemented.

```
function quote_search(json) {

    var database = firebase.database();

    var tickerSymbol = json.symbol;
    var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

    alert(tickerSymbol);


    database.ref('users/' + userId).update({

        "current_ticker": tickerSymbol

    });//end firebasecall


    database.ref("users").orderByChild(userId + "/current_ticker").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {

        var userCurrentTicker = snapshot.val().current_ticker;


        var test = localStorage.setItem('tickerStored', userCurrentTicker);


    });//END FIREBASE

    location.reload();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `alert` blocks the code from running until it is dismissed. Because of this, the later code hasn't yet run while the alert is being displayed.

I don't know firebase, but I'd wager that something before your `alert` takes some time to complete, and that you shouldn't run the later code until it does. You might find the same issue between the two queries.

You should look at the documentation for the various methods you've used, and see if they return [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), or accept callbacks as arguments. In either case, these are mechanisms to wait for something to be finished before doing something else, and you will likely find the bug disappears if you make use of them.

If that's not the issue, it could be that your `location.reload()` is causing the browser to reload the page before the response has come in from the server and so the `child_added` event has fired. Try moving or removing the `location.reload()` call.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything obvious in the documentation. I wonder if it's not actually the alert, but random chance due to a race condition. Try switching the order of the two `database.ref(...` sections, so that the `child_added` listener is set up before the update.

Comment: Oh, you might be doing `location.reload()` before the `child_added` event has had a chance to come in. Remove `location.reload()` -- does it work then?

Comment: OK, I added that to the answer.